# gnuplot: italics in a portion of a label

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Sorry for the (probably) basic question but I'm just getting started with gnuplot. What I'd like is to create an axis label with a portion of it in italics. Something like:

xlabel: Not italics, *italics*

I understand it's easy to set a label to display italics (set xlabel font "Times-Italic", 20), but is it possible to have only a portion of the label in italics?

Comment: Unfortunately, that depends on the terminal. For `set terminal postscript eps enhanced` you can use `set xlabel "not italics, {/Times-Italic italics}"`. But other terminals like `pdfcairo` at the moment don't support font styles for the enhanced text mode, see also [bold enhanced text in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428338/bold-enhanced-text-in-gnuplot). This was already reported as bug: http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1240/.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It turns out I was encountering almost exactly the same situation as outlined in the bug report. I can use postscript eps enhanced and convert afterwords. This helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you can use the enhanced text mode to change the font for parts of a string:

```
set termoption enhanced
set xlabel "not italics, {/Times-Italic italics}"
```

Unfortunately, that behaviour is not supported by all terminals, see [bold enhanced text in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428338/bold-enhanced-text-in-gnuplot) and the related [bug report #1240](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1240/).

It works e.g. with the `postscript` and `png` terminals, but does *not* work with `pngcairo` and `pdfcairo`.

Comment: You can also use `{/:Italic foo}` to avoid re-specifying the font name. This works in Gnuplot 5, but I'm not sure if it's new.

Comment: Works on pdf terminal too

Comment: @reid That was introduced with version 5 and is indeed the way to go nowadays