# How to italic text in Times new roman font in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to produce a plot with font of Times new roman in Jpeg terminal.
Gnuplot 4.6 is installed in Windows. I have tried with JPEG terminal and ended with following result by code:

```
# this script for compare remaining ice area
 reset
 set term png large font "times new roman" 20 size 700,500 enhanced #500,400  
 set output 'Compare.png'

#
 set xlabel "{/=15 {/Italic Time} (min)}"
 set ylabel "{/=15 {/Italic Remaining ice area} (percent)}"
 set xrange [0:75]
 set yrange [0.5:1.01]
 set key top right 
 plot 'ice_example.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 8 lc rgb 'red' lw 3 title 'Free surface LBM' ,\
      'ice_mass.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 5 lc rgb 'black' lw 5 title 'Experiment'

 unset multiplot
 set term win
 unset output
```

When I change `term png` to `term jpeg`, output file is not produced. Also It does not work with `{/Times New Roman-Italic Time} (min)` for label.
Thanks for advance. [image]

Comment: `{/Times-Italic label}` in combination with `png` terminal should work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038368/gnuplot-italics-in-a-portion-of-a-label

Comment: Yes, I tried that one. I got this error: gdImageStringFT: fontconfig: Didn't find expected font family. Perhaps URW Type 1 fonts need installing? while printing string Time with font Times-Italic

Comment: I think the title is misleading because the problem is specific to one terminal. Plotting line graphs in jpeg is in general a bad idea because I doesn't look good with that kind of compression.

Comment: Problem solved by comment of @ewcz . Figure format should be jpg so after having esp, I decided to convert esp to jpg. Thanks all.